# Sprite wrong position on screen

Tags: libgdx

I want to render one sprite on top of another one. I create both sprites using same coordinates and while debuging I can see that they have same position but still one is being rendered beneath another and slightly to the left. Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? here is my code where I create sprites:

```
Sprite sprite1 = new Sprite(new Texture("1.png"));
sprite1.setScale(1/PPM);
Sprite sprite2 = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(...));
sprite2.setScale(1/PPM);
sprite1.setPosition(x,y);
sprite2.setPosition(x,y);
```

Could it have something to do with scaling? Or maybe the fact that second sprite is created from TextureRegion?

Comment: Screenshot? This isn't nearly enough code for us to help you, too

Answer (score 1):

Check the origins of the sprites. if one has its pivot in the middle and the other one top left for example then they appear in different positions.